# How to add specific value of a data frame to a linear regression based on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression, lm

I tried to extract a specific value from one dataframe (df in my example,specific value is "red" from the first column ) and to use it as an independent variable in a linear regression that is based on another data frame that have this value as a column.I save this value as character but I got an error (desc. is below). How can I add this value to ba apart of the lm function that is based on another dataframe?

```
df <- read.table(text = " color birds    wolfs     
                  red           9         7 
                  red           8         4 
                  red           2         8 
                  red           2         3 
                  black         8         3 
                  black         1         2 
                  black         7         16 
                  black         1         5 
                  black         17        7 
                  black         8         7 
                  black         2         7 
                  green         20        3 
                  green         6         3 
                  green         1         1 
                  green         3         11 
                  green         30         1  ",header = TRUE)

df1 <- read.table(text = " red birds    wolfs     
                   10         9         7 
                   8          8         4 
                   11         2         8 
                   8          2         3 
                   3          8         3 
                   4          1         2 
                   8          7         16 
                   9          1         5 
                   10         17        7 
                   8          8         7 
                   6          2         7     ",header = TRUE)
# I extracted the desired value than I added it to the new lm function and got an error:
 df[1,1]
[1] red
Levels: black green red
lm<-lm(birds~df[1,1],data=df1)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = birds ~ df[1, 1], data = df1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'df[1, 1]')
# I also tried to change the value into character :
b<-as.character(df[1,1])
b
[1] "red"
lm<-lm(birds~ b ,data=df1)
but got the same error:Error in model.frame.default(formula = birds ~ b, data = df1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'b')
```

Comment: for a regression the variables must have the same length. Use `lm(df$birds~df[,1])` for instance or `lm(birds~df1[[as.character(df[1,1])]],data=df1)`

Comment: Hello @etienne, I don't think that It answerd my needs as I would like to use the df specific value as a column in the lm function that is based on the df1 data frame.Is there any way to "paste" this value as a text / string into the lm function?

Comment: what regression do you exactly want to run ? predict df1$birds on df1$red ?

Comment: yes, but this is a part of an automatic code so I need to insert a specific value from the first df ( "red" ) into the lm function. lm<-lm(birds~ red ,data=df1)

Comment: ok, see my answer it should be what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use

```
onValue<-as.character(df[1,1]) # "red"
reg<-lm(birds~eval(as.symbol(onValue)),data=df1) # regression
```

Also, don't assign your regression to an object called `lm` as it is the function and could be confusing.

The `eval(as.symbol(onValue))` tells `R` to run the regression on the column of `df1` which has the name of `onValue` (in this case, "red")

Answer (score 2):

If you want a different approach for this, I find `update` to be very good with such tasks:

```
#create a formula outside of lm. This can be a simple one against
#the intercept or one that you already use
form <- birds ~ 1

#then add the new variable using paste + update 
#the . ~ . says include everything before and after the tilde ~
#that existed in original formula  
form <- update(form, paste('. ~ . + ', df[1,1]))
#> form
#birds ~ red

lm <- lm(form, data=df1)

Call:
lm(formula = form, data = df1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          red  
      2.339        0.462
```

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR , Intersting solution, works great.